# Configuring PINB.4 and PINB.5 in AVR ATMega 169 to work as input pins and to enable pull up?

Tags: embedded, avr

I want to configure two AVR butterfly boards in such a way that PORT D is an output port in the first one and two pins of this PORT D are connected to pins B.4 and B.5 of port B of the second AVR butterfly board. I also want to enable pull-ups on these port B pins.  Is this configuration correct for the second AVR ? Is there something that i am missing?

```
  //Init port pins
DDRB = 0x00;
    PORTB |= 0X30;

 //Enable pin change interrupt on PORTB
 PCMSK1 = 0X30;
 EIFR = 0XC0;
 EIMSK = 0XC0;
```

SIGNAL(SIG_PIN_CHANGE1)-- Pin change interrupt of PIN B.4
{..}
SIGNAL(SIG_PIN_CHANGE2)-- Pin change interrupt of PIN B.5
{..... }

Answer (score 1):

You have set up you PORT B correctly but it wouldn't hurt to improve your coding conventions a little.

```
DDRB&= ~(1<<PB0)|(1<<PB1);
PORTB|= (1<<PB0)|(1<<PB1);
```

Unless I am miss-understanding what your trying to accomplish, I don't think your interrupts are configured correctly.

**PB4** and **PB5** correspond to **PCINT12** and **PCINT13** respectively.

Since both correspond to Pin Change Interrupt Enable 1 you'll want to only have that pin enabled.

```
EIMSK = (1<<PCIE1);
```

You don't actually need to set **EIFR** unless your trying to manually trigger an interrupt.  This register gets flagged automatically whenever a pin change occurs.

In **PCMSK1** you want to set **PCINT13** and **PCINT12**

```
PCMSK1 |= (1<<PCINT12)|(1<<PCINT13);
```

This enables interrupts on the corresponding pins.

Also SIGNAL is depreciated.  #include [avr/interrupt.h](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html) and use ISR.

```
ISR(PCINT1_vect){}
```

Both Pin changes will be handled by this vector.

Hope this clears things up a bit.